# How to use CanvasAuthorizer.GetLoginUrl in v5?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade my ASP.NET WebForms IFrame Canvas app from Facbook C# SDK 4.02 to 5.03 beta. Most of the changes are fairly straight forward. However, I'm not 100% sure about CanvasAuthorizer.GetLoginUrl().

Here's my code for v4.02

```
CanvasAuthorizer _authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer {Perms = "publish_stream,offline_access"};

Uri authurl = _authorizer.GetLoginUrl(new HttpRequestWrapper(Request));
CanvasRedirect(authurl.ToString());
```

And here's my best guess for v5.03 based on the php example at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth

```
CanvasAuthorizer _authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer {Perms = "publish_stream,offline_access"};

Dictionary<string, object> parameters =
    new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"scope", _authorizer.Perms},
            {"client_id", _authorizer.AppId},
            {"redirect_uri", _authorizer.ReturnUrlPath},
            {"response_type", "token"}
        };
Uri authurl = _authorizer.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
CanvasRedirect(authurl);
```

Will this work? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I got it to work using the following:

```
CanvasAuthorizer _authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer {Perms = "publish_stream,offline_access"};
if (!_authorizer.IsAuthorized())
{
    _authorizer.HandleUnauthorizedRequest();
}
```

Comment: I also enabled "POST for Canvas" in my Facebook application settings. I'm not sure if that made a difference or not.